# JPA ManyToMany persist only one side

Tags: java, spring, jpa, many-to-many

I have the table User in relation of ManyToMany with Radio like the tables below. In this relation only the method `saveUser` persist in relationship table. To summarize only the dominant side is persisted in USER and RADIO_USER table. How I persist the other side?

table USER:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| user_account_id    | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+--------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

table RADIO:

```
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| radio_id              | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| name                  | varchar(128)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

table RADIO_USER:

```
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| account_radio_id   | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| radio              | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| user_account       | bigint(20) | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
+--------------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

USER Entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "RADIO_USER",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_account", referencedColumnName = "user_account_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "radio", referencedColumnName = "radio_id")})
List<Radio> radios;

@Transactional
public void saveUser(User user) {
    user.setRadios(radioDao.getAll(Radio.class));
    entityManager.persist(user);
}
```

RADIO Entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="radios")
List<User> users;

@Transactional
public void saveRadio(Radio radio) {
    radio.setUsers(userDao.getAllUsersByRole(User.Role.ROLE_ADMIN));
    entityManager.persist(radio)
}
```

Comment: If I change the dominant side then this is persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the relationship is bidirectional and for Hibernate the owner side is the side which is used to know that association exists. Then for this I need use this code:

```
@Transactional
public void save(Radio radio) {
    List<User> users = userDao.getAllUsersByRole(User.Role.ROLE_ADMIN);

    for (User user : users) {
        user.getRadios().add(radio);
    }

    radio.setUsers(users);
    entityManager.persist(radio)
}
```

See [@ManyToMany(mappedBy = “foo”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111607/manytomanymappedby-foo) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want Cascading.

Refer to: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading

Comment: What are you using as your JPA implementation?

Comment: I am using Hibernate.