# JPA Annotations with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am working on JPA project and I need your help.

I have two classes, “Person” and “Leader” which inherits from Person.

```
@Entity   
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)    
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;


    @Column(unique = true)    
    private String personId;

}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class Leader extends Person implements Serializable {

    private List < Person > listTeam;

    public void addPersonInTeam(Person e) {

        listTeam.add(e);
    }
}
```

My question Is, do I need to have JPA annotations @OneToMany or something else before private List listTeam in class Leader?

Thank you very much

Comment: i suggest to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883033/is-it-possible-to-add-jpa-annotation-to-superclass-instance-variables , because i see much more issues than missing annotation on list. If it will not help, leave a note.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to put Person as abstract? or to add @MappedSuperClass? But in this case Person will not be persistant, although I need it to be persistant. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, of course you need a OneToMany or a ManyToMany annotation. Hibernate won't guess what the association is for you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to extend? Maybe some simple boolean `isLeader` is enough in your case?

Comment: so you suggest that I have only the class Person which contains boolean isLeader and List<Person> which should be empty if the person is not leader?

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes It's a better approach to avoid Inheritance.

Comment: @TER: It depends. Maybe you need a `Team` entity too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a mapping between the two classes because for Hibernate the association is not relevant here, you have to use annotations in both sides and I guess you will need a `OneToMany` mapping here :

Here's the mapping that you are seraching for:

**In Person class:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String personId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="leader_id")
    private Leader leader;
    //getter and setter

}
```

**In Leader class:**

```
@Entity
public class Leader extends Person implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "leader")
    private List <Person> listTeam;
    //getter and setter

    public void addPersonInTeam(Person e) {
        listTeam.add(e);
    }
}
```

For further information you can see these links:

- **[Hibernate – One-to-Many example (Annotation)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)**.
- **[Hibernate One To Many Annotation tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/)**.

**Note:**

I don't see the use of the field `personId` in the `Person` class, there's no need to use two differents ids.

**EDIT:**

To answer your questions:

1. The `@JoinColumn(name="leader_id")` is not mandatory, but it's used to specify the foreign key name.
2. If the relation is `ManyToMany` the `mappedBy` property is used to specify the owner of the relationship, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111607/manytomanymappedby-foo) for more details.

Comment: Thank you very very much @chsdk, it's much more clear now, but I have additional questions:

1- @JoinColumn(name="leader_id") is mandatory is this case ? why ?
2- if the relation is ManyToMany (a person can be part of many leader's team), the mappedBy side is not that important? Whether it is in the Person or Leader side should work (but the performance will not be the same) right ?
3- the fact that Person is not abstract class is absolutely OK right? Thank you very very much

Comment: Thank you very much chsdk, it's absolutely clear about the owner side of mappedBy, but you said "If the relation is ManyToMany the mappedBy property is optional," ? As I understand it's not very important which side is the owner in case of ManyToMany, but I need to choose a side right ? I mean if I leave only @ManyToMany in both sides without using mappedBy, it will not be a bidirectional link right?

Comment: Sorry I don't think it's optional, my bad, you have to specify the owner of the relationship, I edited my answer.